# What's the mathematical field called where functions create and delete functions?

Tags: functions, terminology

**Motivation**

In the field of modular, reconfigurable robotics there are some groups which use term rewriting, or specifically graph rewriting to describe the reconfiguration process of the modular robots. Grammar rules reflect state changes:

$$
a   b \rightarrow  a - c
$$

would correspond to the real-world event in which a robot in state $a$ meets a robot in state $b$. The "$-$"-token reflects a physical connection. And the rule states that the robot in state $b$ transitions into state $c$. This one rule is valid for the entire population of robots. The word "stochastic" is used in this context to reflect that robots in state $a$ and $b$ are picked at random from a large population of robots.

**General case**

Suppose we write this as:

$$
f(P_{t}(x)) = P_{t+1}(x)
$$

with $P_{t+1}(x)$ the distribution of states over the population, and $f$ our set of rewriting rules. It just does not seem to describe the same system. For example, suppose I would generalize a bit from rewriting states to rewriting functions:

$$
f(a)   g(a) \rightarrow  g(a) h(a)
$$

which would reflect the situation that in a set of functions (with unique names $f,g,h$), we would take a function $f$ and a function $g$, would replace $f$ with $g$ and would replace $g$ with $h$. The function $h$ can be taken out of a set of predefined functions, or be composed out of $f$ and $g$. The function $f$ here is "deleted". So, there is some kind of quantity of "occurrence" attached to each function.

There must be a mathematical discipline that handles this type of function annihilation and creation. Or birth-death processes for functions. How is it called?

Comment: The fact that what you're creating and annihilating are functions seems secondary. You're just creating and annihilating some things. Anyway, this reminds me of what John Baez is calling "network theory"; in particular it seems related to Petri nets (http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/networks/).

Comment: Places in Petri nets can indeed generate and annihilate so-called tokens. However, Petri nets are a bit how a computer scientist tackles this problem. I was hoping for a more rigorous mathematical approach. A certain generalization of category theory for example. There must exist many "self-rewriting mathematical objects" different from grammar rules that I do not know about.